# jekyll - make a list of page.tags

Tags: tags, jekyll

I'm new to jekyll and am working on building my site.

I have a "posts" layout where I'd like to have all the tags associated with the post appear in the left column. The problem I'm running into is that using {{ page.tags }} returns a list of tags that are not comma-separated and looks messy. See here for an  [example](http://johnstantongeddes.org/ecological%20genetics/2013/03/28/thursday.html).

The html code for the layout page is:

```
<div class="span3">
    </br>
    <img src="{{ page.root }}assets/img/glyphicons_045_calendar.png" /> {{ page.date | > date: "%d %B %Y" }}    
    </br> 
    <img src="{{ page.root }}assets/img/glyphicons_066_tags.png" /> {{ page.tags }}
 </div>

<div class="span9">
    <h1> {{ page.title }} </h1>
    {{ content }}
</div>
```

Any advice on how to (a) get the tags list to be comma-separated and (b) wrap around so it stays within the left column?  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might try to put them inside a `<p>` tag so they can wrap around.

To have them comma-separated, you can follow the jekyll docs and use:

```
{{ page.tags | array_to_sentence_string }} => foo, bar, and baz
```

As is said [in the Jekyll wiki](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Liquid-Extensions).

Comment: Thanks! Those tips did exactly what I wanted, and I appreciate the link the the Jekyll wiki which I had seen but forgotten while trying to put this all together.

Answer (score 5):

For more precise control over what you can do with tags use the `for` operator:

```
<ul>
{% for tag in page.tags %}
    <li> {{tag}} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This example is taken verbatim from somewhere. There are also more [control structures](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers) to choose from.

Comment: I like this way too but how would you comma separate them and remove the last comma?

Comment: For anyone else needing this, I ended up using {% if forloop.last == false %},{% endif %}